# asp.net-mvc jquery dialog url with target=_blank doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery dialog showing a few items, with a link to open the item's order information in another window. This works fine on a regular view, but when I use `target=_blank` on a jQuery modal dialog, it does not open another browser window and instead navigates the page under the dialog to the URL.

Any ideas how to work around this, to get a popup from a jQuery dialog? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JavaScript `window.open()` method instead.  A sample usage would be like this:

```
window.open("http://www.mydomain.com", "mywindow")
```

You can view some documentation here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml.

This should give you the functionality you are looking for.